# How to change the value of a textView within a widget, from the value of a textEdit in another activity

Tags: android

If I have a widget that has a textView within it, and then a different class with an activity with a editText, is there a way to change the widget textView value, to the same value of the editText?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using an Intent to switch between your activities.

You could use the method putExtra to send some data.
In the activity where you have the textEdit :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, myClass.class);
intent.putExtra("key", "StringFromEditText");
startActivity(intent);
```

And get it in the activity where you have the textView :

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String content = extras.getString("key");
```

Comment: It asks me to create a method for the getIntent when I put that 2nd bit of code in.

Comment: I'm getting confused now. When I have my main activity open that contains a editText and click the save button, I want it to close the application and then update the widget's textView with the contents of the editText.

Comment: Oh, i wasn't aware that this string must be saved. My code won't work for you need. You should check out about "preferences". Here is 2 usefull links : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html and http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences

Answer (score 0):

Put the value of the EditText in a a database, file, or SharedPreferences in the activity that it's in, and read that back out in your widget.